# Can we have objective knowledge?

Tags: epistemology

Is agentive activity included in every representation (intension)? If so the extension of every representation includes some information about the interactivity between the representing agent and the thing being represented. For example: iconic, visual concepts (what a dog looks like) presupposes the activity of visual perception; namely looking at a dog, paying attention to certain salient features, committing this to long term memory and so on. Or to put it another way, you can’t have information about some x, without some amount of interactivity (A1,A2,…,An) relating agent y to x. vis., [A1->n(x,y)]. Does this not imply that there is no such thing as objective knowledge?

Comment: Alternatively: Do you only understand x to the extent that you interact with x (or to the extent that you can make sense of a report of how someone else went about interacting with x)?

Comment: This question is way too big... Can you narrow it in some way?

Comment: Virmaior: Can you have a concept of something that doesn’t also include some information about the interactivity between the representing agent and the thing being represented?

Comment: I probably should have appended “concepts” with “a posteriori concepts”

Comment: a posteriori knowledge includes interaction by definition.

Comment: Virmaior: would the same apply to apriori?

Comment: Most would say that the extension of the concept of “dog” is a non-empty set containing all dogs or at least an example of one. The problem is that if agentive activity is included, the set with all the dogs in it contains you as well. So the intension >dog< has the extension <dogs, people, interaction>.

Comment: I don't know what you're intending to mean by saying "most" nor am I entirely clear on what you mean by "concept." Most of the lingo you are using is from philosophy of language, but the question you are asking is much larger in scope. It sounds like you're trying to argue the following: (1) All of our knowledge requires we be *in situ* observers. (2) Objective knowledge requires that this be false. Therefore, we cannot have objective knowledge.

Comment: But you need to tell us what you think "objective knowledge" means to complete the picture. But if you do that it should probably be easy for you to answer yourself whether you think it is possible.

Comment: I agree with all virmaior's comments. Perhaps this can serve as a counterexample: I know that water is H2O. I may have had to interact with water to come to know that it is H2O, but in the end the proposition I know contains no information about how I came to know that water is H2O or what kind of interactions I have with water.

Comment: Leibnewtz. Interesting point. Knowing part of the chemical composition of water (H2O) is pertinent to scientific or industrial activities (snowflake formation, electrolysis, etc.), but it’s not relevant to the macro level interactions you or I have with it: drinking it, bathing in it, boiling it to produce steam, freezing it to cool your beverages, wet tee-shirt night at the pub, etc.

Comment: As I’ve posted above “…, or to the extent that you can make sense of a report of how someone else went about interacting with x?” I’d be cautious about ascribing the cognitive attitude ‘knowledge’ to yourself in this instance, since this information would be hearsay to you. Someone, somewhere down the chain of command had to engage in some interaction in order to obtain the information and this is (presumably) embedded in the concept.

Comment: Two things. (1) It is possible to frame all of our knowledge in the form of prohibitions on what you can do with it. For example, there are limitations on the circumstances under which you can heat water up without boiling it. (2) There is also a lot of knowledge that is not known to anybody, e.g. - the implementation details of a computer program or contents of a book. The point of having such records is that you don't have to remember it.

Comment: @jimpliciter  "Most would say that the extension of the concept of “dog” is a non-empty set containing all dogs" -- For my understanding, what is the extension of the concept of "unicorn?" And what is the extension of the concept of Captain Ahab?

Comment: @jimpliciter If knowledge can't be transmitted from one person to another then I can hardly think of anything that anyone knows. As long as those who tell you that e.g. "Water is H2O" are trustworthy, cite strong evidence and methodology for their discovery, and the evidence for their discovery is not outweighed by evidence to the contrary, I believe it's safe to say you know that water is H2O.

Comment: @user4894. The concepts ‘unicorn’ ‘Captain Ahab’, ‘Humpty Dumpty’, etc., all have the same extension- the null set.

Comment: @leibnewtz. Regarding ‘water=H20’check out this blog and the work of Michael Weisberg (Water is not H20):
http://branemrys.blogspot.com.au/2011/10/water-is-not-h2o.html
http://www.phil.upenn.edu/~weisberg/Homepage/Papers.html

Comment: @jimpliciter But surely the utterance "Ahab is Captain of the Pequod" is true; and "Moby Dick is a sardine" is false. You disagree? Every educated English-speaking person knows the referents of those sentences.

Comment: @user4894. Check out the following two papers: Pete Mandik’s ‘Unicorn Argument’ and Uriah Kriegal’s ‘Merely Intentional Objects’:
http://philpapers.org/rec/MANBOT
http://philpapers.org/rec/KRITDO
These two papers offer solutions that I think relate to your question.

Comment: @user4894. I’m fond of the idea (which Mandik more or less proposes in his paper) that fiction is constructed from combinatorial and analogical transformations on a base of straight forward knowledge of the given natural world. Integrally speaking fiction has no extension (ie. the null set), but componential-ly it does. Think fiction as chimera: the beast as whole has no extension, but its parts do.

Comment: @jimpliciter The article raises a fair point, maybe water is not identical to H2O. Nevertheless my point still stands: our knowledge of propositions such as those regarding the microstructure of water don't contain any content regarding our experience of water, though experience of water may be necessary to arrive at such knowledge.

Comment: @leibnewtz. I suppose if you chanced upon an unfamiliar tool, there’s no reason to suppose that instructions for its use are somehow contained within it.

Answer (score 0):

To break this down a bit, consider that "having objective knowledge" can be construed in two ways. (1) You can "have objective knowledge" in a limited sense in which you are simply correct in asserting some statement, without knowledge of whether such statement is in fact true or false. I think this must be possible in a sort of "infinite monkeys on typewriters" type of way: given an infinite set of statements, at least one must be objectively true, therefore objective knowledge is possible. But what I think you are really asking is (2) can we know that we have objective knowledge? That is more problematic. This was Descartes' quest in *Discourse on the Method*: is there some basic proposition that we can definitively say is true or false?

This question cannot really be answered because answering it involves oneself in the question itself. If we say, "no it's not possible," then we have set that proposition up as objective truth and thereby contradicted ourselves.

I think it would be useful to consider what your standard of proof is. Objective knowledge in mathematics is more strictly defined than it is in the empirical sciences, which is more strictly defined than law, which is more strictly defined than history.

To address your point about agentive activity: it does not really matter so long as the resultant proposition remains true. That is, as long as you can account for the effects of agentive activity, then you can still appreciate it objectively. Or perhaps it has no effect at all -- you seem to have assumed that it always does. It is true that since we are finite, instantiated beings, we always posses a point of view or vantage point; yet it does not follow that there aren't certain vantage points from which an objective assessment can be had.